# how to get data from json array in react js

Tags: reactjs

i am getting the json from api but it is not converting to array previously i got the values but from this code i am not getting the value

this is my code:

```
componentWillMount() {
    let initialFilename;
    fetch('http://localhost/Generator/FetchfileDetails.php')
        .then(response=>{
            return response.json();
        }).then(data=>{
            alert(data.filename);
        });
}
```

the key value in my json is filename is to be stored in array how to do???

Answer (score 1):

First thing keep in mind don't use componentWillMount() method to fetch the data.

Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#how-can-i-make-an-ajax-call

Use following,

```
componentDidMount(){  
     fetch("http://localhost/Generator/FetchfileDetails.php") 
        .then(res=> res.json())
        .then(data=>{ //here you can set data to state })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i recommended u used package axios for GET data,it's so easily to use..

```
axios.get('API').then(response=>{console.log(response)})
```

You can insert this code in the componentDidMount function

if u want to see the full documentation axios,[This Link](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosdeleteurl-config)

Answer (score 0):

You can try instead of response.json() you can do:

```
fetch("http://localhost/Generator/FetchfileDetails.php") .then(response=>{ return JSON.parse(response) }).then(data=>{ alert(data);})
```

Also, if you say the response is supposed to be an array, you can't use data.filename , you have to do data['filename'] , data.filename is for object responses

Comment: [{"slno":"2","filename":"newfile1txt","filepath":"Uploads\/TextFiles\/newfile1txt"},{"slno":"4","filename":"newfile2txt","filepath":"Uploads\/TextFiles\/newfile2txt"}] my json is like this i am not getting the filename i am getting undifined..